# MySQL C# - Export database

Tags: c#, mysql, database

I'm a beginner so I'll try to explain what I'm trying to do so please bear with me:

I'm developing a db application on C# and I'm using MySQL (Workbench) to manage my database so when I establish the connection in the C# project I use the following connection string:

```
string MyConnectionString = "Server=localhost;Database=catalogue;Uid=root;Pwd=1234;";
```

But I'd like to send the project to a friend to check it out so what would be the easiest way to send him the DB as well? Is there a way to send it as a single file (something like an Access db) and modify the connection string so that the project works without him adding the db to the localhost.

Thank you!

Comment: MySQL can be exported into a basic zip file (or similar, like a .tar.gz file). However that is not a database. It still needs importing into a MySQL server. You sound as though you want something like SQLite, where the physical database is easily portable.

Comment: I eventually switched to Access, even though I don't like it, at least its familiar. Nevertheless thanks for your advice, your comment was voted useful!